# Gaps and Islands problem in PostGIS for GPS traces

Tags: postgis, postgresql, gps, trace, st-makeline

I'm using `ST_MakeLine` to create traces of ship movements. The query below yields all the GPS points on a certain day, and I'm using `ST_Within` to only find ships in the navigable portions of the river.

```
SELECT gps.basedatetime, gps.geom
from ais_2018 as gps
join dissolved_nav_waterway dnw  
on st_within(gps.geom, dnw.wkb_geometry)
where status = 0
and vesselname = 'HIGH ROLLER'
and basedatetime::date = '2018-08-25'
group by gps.basedatetime, gps.geom 
order by gps.basedatetime
```

However, if I try to use ST_Makeline, I get an erroneous straight line over the land, which I determined is because the GPS data has a gap where it wasn't being recorded for several hours. Query below.

```
select st_makeline(geom)
from problem p
```

Is there any way I can split the line into two segments at this gap or otherwise remove the erroneous straight line? I've read a bit about the "gaps and islands" problem but I can't seem to find a solution. Photo attached, the straight line is the error, which represents the ship moving northeast without its GPS on, turning GPS on, and then moving south to southwest.

[image: gps trace here]

Answer (score 4):

You will have to delineate a dimensional threshold in order to solve the *Islands and Gaps* problem; you could e.g. define an upper limit for the GPS check-in interval, and split the sequence accordingly:

```
SELECT  ST_MakeLine(geom ORDER BY basedatetime) AS geom
FROM    (
    SELECT *,
           SUM(__isl) OVER(ORDER BY basedatetime) AS _mkl
    FROM   (
        SELECT gps.*,
               COALESCE((gps.basedatetime - LAG(gps.basedatetime) OVER(ORDER BY gps.basedatetime) > <TIME_THRESHOLD>)::INT, 0) AS __isl
        FROM   ais_2018 AS gps
        JOIN   dissolved_nav_waterway AS dnw  
          ON   ST_Intersects(gps.geom, dnw.wkb_geometry)
        WHERE  gps.status = 0
          AND  gps.vesselname = 'HIGH ROLLER'
          AND  gps.basedatetime::DATE = '2018-08-25'
    ) sq
) q
GROUP BY
        _mkl
;
```

This should return a separate *LineString* for all parts of a trace spearated by more than `<TIME_THRESOLD>`.

---

Note that you could use the *Window Functions* to `PARTITION BY` your attributes, so that e.g. the query creates these paths in batch, if needed, for all unique combinations of `gps.status` and/or `gps.vesselname` and/or `gps.basedatetime::DATE`:

```
SELECT  status,
        vesselname,
        basedatetime::DATE,
        ST_MakeLine(geom ORDER BY basedatetime) AS geom
FROM    (
    SELECT *,
           SUM(__isl) OVER(PARTITION BY gps.status, gps.vesselname, gps.basedatetime::DATEORDER BY basedatetime) AS _mkl
    FROM   (
        SELECT gps.*,
               COALESCE((gps.basedatetime - LAG(gps.basedatetime) OVER(PARTITION BY gps.status, gps.vesselname, gps. ORDER BY gps.basedatetime) > <TIME_THRESHOLD>)::INT, 0) AS __isl
        FROM   ais_2018 AS gps
        JOIN   dissolved_nav_waterway AS dnw  
          ON   ST_Intersects(gps.geom, dnw.wkb_geometry)
    ) sq
) q
GROUP BY
        status, vesselname, basedatetime::DATE, _mkl
;
```